# Is "in which" relevant here?

Tags: grammaticality, clauses

I am writing the following sentence.

> In contrast to the object modeling, (ABC et al., 2009) present an approach for urban object recognition using shape knowledge **in which** a set of features describing the object shape and their spatial context are introduced in order to classify objects.

I am not sure whether I used the correct clause to get the clear meaning of the sentence. Is "in which" correct in this case?

Answer (score 1):

"in which" sounds perfectly natural here.

However, here are a couple things to look at.

- What/Who is the subject doing the presenting?
- "the object shape" vs. "the object's shape" (general vs specific)
- "their" vs. "its" (one object shape vs many object shapes)
- "in order" (ambiguous: "to be able to" vs. "in a particular sorted order")

In accordance with the above, I would rephrase it as:

> In contrast to the object modeling, **ABC et al. (2009) presents**<sup>*</sup> an approach for urban object recognition using shape knowledge in which a set of features describing the object'**s** shape **and spatial context** are **introduced to classify** objects.

<sup>*</sup> *Present* and *presents* would both be okay here. I am American and I favor *presents*; a British English speaker might favor *present*.